# root path for php files in Linux apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, root

I am having problems with locating files with php `include` on my Ubuntu server.

**structure of site**

```
/var/www/
     home/index.php
     include/header.php
```

When I try to insert the following `include_once('/include/header.php')` in the file **home/index.php** it does not work.

however if I change that to `include_once('../include/header.php')`, it works fine, but to have consistency through out my site I can't allow this

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: the absolute path will always work `include_once('/var/www/include/header.php')`

Comment: @Dagon if I do that I won't be able to test it in xampp

Comment: well now you tell me you want that, do i look psychic :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your document root is `/var/www/` then you can use:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/header.php';
```

Typically, PHP gets the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` correct so you can usually rely on that.

If you want to include the file relative to the script that is doing the include, you can do:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../include/header.php';
```

Comment: Thanks this works, it's only a shame there's no dreamweaver user friendly solution

Comment: Why doesn't dreamweaver like it?

Comment: it doesn't let you preview php files from the top file navigation, but I guess it's not a big deal

Answer (score 2):

The leading slash indicates an absolute path. Most applications will define an `APP_ROOT` constant or something similar early in the cycle to solve these problems.

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then later on you can include files with:

```
include(APP_ROOT . '/includes/header.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/header.php');